# Prove A$\subset\mathbb{R}$ is path-connected iff A is an interval

Tags: general-topology

> Prove A$\subset\mathbb{R}$ is path-connected iff A is an interval (open, closed or half-open).

Let $I$ be the interval with end points $a<$b.

Let $\phi$:[0,1]$\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi$(t)=$a+t(b-a)$. Then $\phi$(0)=a and $\phi$(1)=b and $\phi([0,1])$={$z\in$$\mathbb{R}$: z=$a+t(b-a)$, t$\in$[0,1]}.

On the other hand, we know that A$\subset\mathbb{R}$ is conncted iff A is any interval. I don't know how to proceed, though.

Comment: Every path-connected space is connected. The connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ are precisely the intervals (including the rays and $\Bbb R$ itself).

Comment: It is not generally true that connectedness implies path connectedness, although the converse is always true. But this is not a general problem. This is a specific problem about subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. You have to prove that intervals are path connected and that non-intervals are not path connected.

Comment: @1_likeMaths: You can’t prove that; as Lee Mosher says, it isn’t true in general. But if $A$ is an interval, and $a,b\in A$ with $a<b$, then $[a,b]\subseteq A$, and your $\varphi$ is then a path from $a$ to $b$ that is easily shown to lie wholly inside $A$.

Comment: An interval is exactly a subset $A$ such that given $x,y \in A$, if $x < z < y$ then $z \in A$. Conclude

Comment: You have not proven that closed intervals are path-connected.  To show that $A$ is path-connected, you need to show that for _any_ $x,y\in A$, there is a path in $A$ from $x$ to $y$, not just for the endpoints of the interval.

Comment: @EricWofsey I am not sure how to modify the proof that A is an interval $\implies$ A is path-connected. How about letting  a,b$\in$A arbitrarily and then assume $I$=$[a,b]$$\subseteq$$A$?

Answer (score 1):

$[0,1]$ is a connected space. The continuous image of a connected space is connected.

Suppose  $A\subset \mathbb R$ where $A$ is not an interval. Then there exist $x,y,z$ with $x<y<z$ and $x,z\in A$ and $y\not \in A.$ Suppose $f:[0,1]\to A$ is continuous with $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=z.$  Let $B=\{f(t):t\in [0,1]\}.$ Then $B$ is  a continuous image of $[0,1]$ so $B$ is a connected space.

But $B_1=B\cap (-\infty,y)$ and $B_2=B\cap (y,\infty)$ are non-empty open disjoint subsets of $B$  with $B_1\cup B_2=B,$ so $B$ is not connected,... a contradiction.

So no such $f$ exists. Therefore,  if $A \subset \mathbb R$ and $A$ is not an interval then $A$ is not path-connected.

Remark. It suffices to show that $A$ is not connected, because a disconnected space is not path-connected: If $x<y<z$ with $x,z\in A\subset \mathbb R, $ and $y\not \in A, $  then $\{A\cap (-\infty,y),A\cap (y,\infty)\}$ is a disconnection of $A.$

Further remark. On re-reading your work on the first part I see it is inexact and incomplete. If $J$ is a bounded open real interval  with end-points $a, b$ then either $a$ or $b $ may fail to belong to $J.$ However if $J$ is a (bounded or unbounded) real interval then $J$ is convex: For any $c,d\in J$ with $c\leq d$ we have $[c,d]\subset J.$ So let $f_{c,d}(t)=(1-t)c+td$ for $t\in [0,1].$ Then $f_{c,d}:[0,1]\to J$ is continuous with $f_{c,d}(0)=c$ and $f_{c,d}(1)=d.$